# Angular 6 HostBinding with multiple values?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-hostbinding

I have successfully used `@HostBinding` in my Angular 6 app to apply properties to the host component, as in applying a class when a variable is true:

`@HostBinding('class.compact-ui') isCompact;`

Now, however, I need to assign one of 4 possible classes based on the model of a select menu. For example, user can `red`, `blue`, or `green`.

I suppose I can use multiple host bindings for when any of the colors are true:

`@HostBinding('class.green-ui') uiColor === 'green';`

But that seems wrong. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

To assign multiple classes to a host you can do this:

```
@HostBinding('class') classAttribute: string = 'classA classB';
```

For your case, you could do something like this:

```
@HostBinding('class') classAttribute: string;

// Example function that updates the classAttribute property
// You might handle it differently in your application
updateClassAttribute(color: string, isCompact: boolean) {
  const classes: string[] = [`${color}-ui`];

  if (isCompact) classes.push('compact-ui');

  this.classAttribute = classes.join(' ');
}
```

Note that above function logic can be written in a single line, like this:

```
this.classAttribute = [ ...isCompact ? ['compact-ui'] : [], `${color}-ui` ].join(' ');
```

Also, you might consider using a Redux store (e.g. `@ngrx/store`) for those values (`isCompact`, `color`) if you need them in multiple places in your application.

Answer (score 5):

**Note: This is for the latest versions of angular and may not work on older versions (as per the question title).**

An object can also be returned which will add all the `true` values to the element and remove all the `false` values from the element.

**Note:** This also works with `@HostBinding('style')`.

```js
  /** The size of the button. */
  @Input() size: ButtonSize = 'md';

  /** The classes to attach to the element. */
  @HostBinding('class')
  get elementClasses() {
    return {
      'primary-button': true,
      [`primary-button--${this.size}`]: true,
      'primary-button--color': false,
      'other-class': this.isOtherClass()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with style too:

```
@HostBinding('style')
get style_binding()
{
    return { 
        display: 'grid',
        gap: this.config.internalGap,
        margin: this.config.margin,
        gridArea: this.config.area
    };
}
```